# Live debug .net core microservice in visual studio that’s hosted locally in kubernetes on docker desktop

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, kubernetes, asp.net-core-webapi, docker-desktop

I have set up a simple kubernetes environment on my PC using docker desktop and have a basic ingress controller.

I would like to live debug an Asp.Net Core web api microservice in visual studio that receives a call through the ingress controller so I can do an end to end testing from my front-end.

I can’t find any information on whether this is possible or how other people setup their dev testing environment. So far I have tried using an ExternalService in kubernetes but can’t get it to work with localhost and tried to create a redirect from the ingress controller that just forwards calls on from a certain path but again couldn’t find an approach that worked for me either.

If anyone could tell me if the approaches I am taking work and how to do it or if there is another approach I’m missing, I’d much appreciate it